# 'GSpreadException: the given 'expected_headers' are not uniques' error

Tags: python, sql

I get the following error when trying use the  `get_all_records` function from the   `gspread` library. This worked fine for the past few months but stopped working just now. Added a picture of the sheet as reference.
I am using the following code:

```
mer = input_spreadsheet.worksheet('sheet_1')
sheet_mer = pd.DataFrame(mer.get_all_records())
```

```
GSpreadException                          
      1 mer = input_spreadsheet.worksheet('sheet_1')
----> 2 sheet_mer = pd.DataFrame(mer.get_all_records())

  436         # make sure they are uniques
    437         if len(expected) != len(expected_headers):
--> 438             raise GSpreadException("the given 'expected_headers' are not uniques")
    439 
    440         if not expected & headers == expected:

GSpreadException: the given 'expected_headers' are not uniques
```

[image: Sheet]

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a known issue with suggested alternatives from the developer here:
https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1007